# Wrong result in `netaddr`'s `IPRange.__contains__` (`in`) operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm trying to trace a problem in a piece of code. A short sample is this:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPRange
IPNetwork('127.0.0.4/32') in IPRange('127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.4')
```

Which surprisingly returns `False`.

Obviously the network is contained in the range specified, but the operator returns that it is not.

Inspecting the [recent code for `__contains__`](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L1377) (I thought I might have been fixed by now) after debugging I can see that there is a possible error for the `IPNetwork` case:

```
if isinstance(other, IPNetwork):
    shiftwidth = other._module.width - other._prefixlen
    other_start = (other._value >> shiftwidth) << shiftwidth
    # Start of the next network after other
    other_next_start = other_start + (1 << shiftwidth)
    return (self._start._value <= other_start and self._end._value > other_next_start)
```

Given the setup, the last line should probably be:

```
return (self._start._value <= other_start and self._end._value >= other_next_start - 1)
```

There is also a cleaner solution that is used somewhere else in the module:

```
return self._start._value <= other.start and self._last._value >= other.last
```

It seems like the problem happens because the `other_next_start` is set to the first address (as int) **after** the last ip of the network.

This is proven when trying a case where the network is not even at the "edge" of the range:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPRange
IPNetwork('127.0.0.3/32') in IPRange('127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.4')
```

And again, `False`.

In other words this is wrong because it erroneously extends the network in two ip addresses.

Assuming the the module is widely used I'd like to know if something I'm doing is conceptually wrong given my examples.

### Update:

I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/pull/156) to `netaddr` after running this code:

```
>>> net = IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/30')
>>> rng = IPRange(net.first, net.last)
>>> net in rng
False
>>> for ip in net:
...     print ip in rng
... 
True
True
True
True
```

Which makes no sense to me at all and is explained by my suspicion.